# Fast Search for Vue from Big Json Data

Tags: performance, vue.js, search

I have a Buefy data table in Vue that loads with json data that is rendered through a php file.

I was looking for a search filter in my table that is fast, I already have this:

Template:

```
<b-field label="Search by Bid Price">
          <b-input v-model="search_query.price"/>
        </b-field>
```

Data: `search_query: { price: ""  },`

Computed Function:

```
filter: function() {
      if (this.search_query.price) {
        let price_re = new RegExp(this.search_query.price, "i");
        let data = [];
        for (let i in this.posts) {
          if (
            this.posts[i].price &&
            this.posts[i].price.toString().match(price_re)
          ) {
            data.push(this.posts[i]);
          }
        }
        return data;
      }
      return this.posts;
    }
```

but this is not fast and is slow according to my data which is about 400 rows and more sometimes depending on the query.

Comment: will that make a big difference?

Comment: sorry that was a wrong question. But i dont understand the reason why you are going with regex.  And also not sure why you are populating the data when you are not using it

Comment: I wish you left the question so people who are thinking the same thing can correct themselves

Comment: what do you mean not using it? what do you suggest?

Comment: can you give some more info on how you are saying this as slow? going throw 400 or even more objects should be fairly fast.

Comment: when i start typing the numbers I'm about to search it has little pauses as it filters the data in the table.

Comment: are you looking for something like search as you type?

Comment: Thats basically what I'm looking for yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So What I did was that i used [vue-fuse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fuse) to create a nice and customizable search setup. but I was experiencing a lag effect because I had a heavy json behind my table to search through so I used debounce from [lodash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash) to fix it. and it works like a charm right now.